# dispatch({type: INCREMENT}) вызывает ошибку

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем привет)
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему кнопки в красной рамке вызывают ошибки?
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-payload-counter-cgir2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Была ошибка тут:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ number: number - 1 })}>
        -
</button>
```

Всё остальное работает, в чём ошибка?